# How an autoload/file.vim is loaded?

Tags: plugin-system, autoload

I am on WSL trying to understand why my `fakeclip.vim` doesn't work.

I've added

```
let g:fakeclip_platform = s:PLATFORM
```

into `~/.vim/bundle/vim-fakeclip/autoload/fakeclip.vim`, but I can't access the variable I have created. However I can access `g:fakeclip_terminal_multiplexer_type`.

So I was suspecting vim to not load/use this file. Fakeclip is organized as follow:

```
.vim/bundle/vim-fakeclip/
├── autoload
│   └── fakeclip.vim
├── doc
│   ├── fakeclip.txt
│   └── tags
├── Gemfile
├── plugin
│   └── fakeclip.vim
```

So I executed this:

```
$ echo "let g:foo=42" >> .vim/bundle/vim-fakeclip/plugin/fakeclip.vim
$ echo "let g:bar=42" >> .vim/bundle/vim-fakeclip/autoload/fakeclip.vim
```

But once again, `g:bar` doesn't exist. So I removed the autoload file:

```
$ rm .vim/bundle/vim-fakeclip/autoload/fakeclip.vim
```

But `g:fakeclip_terminal_multiplexer_type` which is only defined in this file is still available.

Of course between each attempt I quit and restarted vim. I also removed `.viminfo` just in case.

Could some explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 6):

autoload plugins are sourced:

- either when we source them explicitly (like in `:runtime autoload/fakeclip.vim`)
- or when we call a function that starts in `foo#bar#whatever()`, it'll source `autoload/foo/bar.vim`, even if the function doesn't exist.

So, if you want to define a variable in an autoload plugin,

- either use a dedicated interface: `:call fakeclip#_init()` which is quite cumbersome and defeats the purpose of using autoload plugins;
- or set the variable in a plain `plugin/` instead;
- or don't even try to set it if you're just trying to access an option, you could instead provide an internal accessor for your option, and use this accessor instead of `g:fakeclip_platform` from your code.

  ```
  function! fakeclip#_platform()
      return get(g:, 'fakeclip_platform', somedefaultvalue)
  endfunction
  ```